# How do I install phantom js in a shared host like hostigator?

Tags: phantomjs

Im trying to install Phantomjs in my share host , is there any way that I can install it just using ftp acess and cpanel?

Thanks!

Comment: I think *Server Fault* may be a better site to ask this question. It's a sister site of Stack Overflow, but more focused on problems like this. Check it out: http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks,I just have asked there!

Comment: SF link: http://serverfault.com/questions/634850/how-do-i-install-phantom-js-in-a-shared-host-like-hostigator

Comment: You're saying, you have tried to install, but what was the problem? How did it fail?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In all probability it won't due to security restrictions imposed by the provider.

Please check with the customer support of the specified vendor (hostigator).